# Custom query for tag and custom tag from 2 post type

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, query, tax-query

I have custom post type called items and added custom taxonomies `type` and `sub-type`.

[image]

**I like to query posts from both `post` and `items` post type that has `art` as either Tags or Sub type.**

Below is what I currently have and it's not working.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => array('items', 'post'),
    'posts_per_page'    => 4,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'sub-type',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => 'art',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tag',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => 'art',
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: The built-in tag taxonomy is `post_tag`.

Comment: To add to @Milo You should avoid using the `name` parameter in a `tax_query`. Due to crappy sanitation, the `tax_query` fails in an really bad unexpected way when a term name has more than one word and/or special characters

Comment: @Milo u meant using `post_tag` instead of `tax_query`? It does not seem to be working in my situation...

Comment: no, `'taxonomy' => 'post_tag'` inside the `tax_query` for built-in tag taxonomy.

Comment: @Milo thank you for the quick response! yes, that seems to be working!

Comment: @PieterGoosen Should I just remove `'field'    => 'name',` then? or use `slug`?

Comment: @PieterGoosen I think I got what u meant. `'field' => 'slug'` should work better than name which I have now ;) Thank you guys!